# current duration of a live video stream with React hls player in r

Tags: reactjs, wowza

I'm using ReactHLS player and that streams a live video. I need to get the current duration of the video and I need to display the same on some other places on the same pages. How can we do it efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the durationchange event
it must support that
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hls